# Can I recover files from an encrypted laptop hard drive?

Tags: system-installation, encryption, data-recovery

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14 in a pen drive using my Win 10 laptop. During installation, I checked the option to encrypt the drive. Since I'm new to Ubuntu I did not know exactly what this option would do.

After I pulled out the pen drive, i could not boot Windows in my laptop. My laptop drive was encrypted I guess, or something else, I don't know what happened.

I booted Ubuntu again but I couldn't access the desktop. It says

> this location could not be displayed. You don't have permissions necessary to view the contents of 'root'.

Can I recover files from my laptop drive? How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover data from an encrypted hard drive on a dead laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862358/how-to-recover-data-from-an-encrypted-hard-drive-on-a-dead-laptop)

Comment: I think you may have deleted your Windows partion by selecting encrypt drive on the Ubuntu install that's why you can't boot to Windows you would need to look at the disk partions to confirm this.

Comment: The option you selected encrypts Ubuntu, not Windows. Please clarify what the partitions were before and, most importantly, what the current partitions are on the drive. Also, are you trying to recover files on the Ubuntu side or on the Windows side?